# Error SOQL 101 while deploying inactive trigger

Tags: trigger, deployment

I have requirement to inactive the trigger on production. For that I am using sales force chengeset functionality.

But I am unable to understand it is giving 101 error if deploying inactive trigger but if I am deploying same trigger as active its not giving error.

I am completely clueless. Any possible reason for that ?

Comment: You must be receiving the error when tests are running while deployment. What you can do is deactivate the trigger and try to run the individual test which is failing in you full sandbox(if you have one) and check the debug log.

Comment: @Manjit..issue is it doesn't give error on deploying active trigger. But inactive trigger deploying giving 101 error... What is reason for that ?

Comment: Perhaps the trigger is suppressing some behavior. I would investigate in the source environment as @manjit_singh suggests and see if you can reproduce the failing tests.